# [msys2][gcc] Wrong output of wprintf() compiling with MSys2's gcc 10.2

Tags: c, windows, gcc, msys2

I need to get this stripped-down C program working on Windows 7 using MSys2's gcc toolchain:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
   for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
      wprintf(L"%s\n", argv[i]);
}
```

The code compiles with

```
gcc -Wall -municode -O2 -march=x86-64 -m64 test.c
```

but gives me the following output

```
>> ./a.exe kk лл
k   (!)
:?:?
```

I have the following questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How would I downgrade the compiler to
   version, say, 9.x, or 10.1? (I'm under the impression that the very
   same program compiled about one year ago used to work correctly)

Edit [1]: Meanwhile I managed to set up a new MSys2 environment using gcc 9.3. The "error" persists, so it's not the compiler.

Edit [2]: "Some programmer dude" (cmp. below) described the "immediate" solution (THX!).

Answer (score 1):

Even for the wide-character [`wprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwprintf) the format `%s` is for *narrow* character strings.

You need to use `%ls` to print wide-character strings:

```
 wprintf(L"%ls\n", argv[i]);
```

---

However this might still not be enough, as the actual encoding of the input (including arguments) might not be what's expected. You need to take into account the encoding used by the terminal the program is running in.

Comment: You're correct, that was wrong and explains the "k". Fixing it, I get the "kk" now...

I have however been using "%s" since I switched from ANSI to Wide. And a program compiled about one year ago used to run "correctly" until (and including) now. Only after recompiling it today, I ran into this. Is there a reasonable explanation?

Comment: @nickles I can't really say. This should have ben the standard behavior since `wprintf` was added in the C95 standard.